# GCMIntentService import errors

Tags: google-app-engine

Please help me. I'm following the Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project tutorial. Straight away I'm getting import errors in the GCMIntentService class.

```
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;
```

I don't know what to do. 
I'm using Eclipse Juno,
GAE Java SDK 1.7.7.1,
Google Plugin 4.2,
Android API 17

I'm very new to this so any advice is welcome

Thank you in advance.
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new update for Eclipse GAE plugin has been released and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually add the Google Cloud Messaging library: look in your Android SDK for the `gcm.jar` file (should be in the extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-client\libs folder in your Android SDK folder).

Answer (score 0):

You  must to remove this rows:

```
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint;
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.Deviceinfoendpoint.Builder;
import com.cloudnotes.deviceinfoendpoint.model.DeviceInfo;
```

and do import again.
It is works for me.